# Showing that an integral of a curve in $\mathbb{C}$ vanishes when the parameter approaches infinity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to solve a problem where you have to use the residue theorem in order to get the value of a certain integral, but I cannot go on from this point:

I need to show that $\int_{0}^\pi f(R+it)dt$ and $\int_\pi^0 f(-R+it)dt$, where $$f(z)=sinh(z)tanh(z)sin(\omega z),\,\omega\in\mathbb{R},$$ tend both to $0$ as $R$ tends to $+\infty$. I guess that the $\sin(\omega(\pm R+it))$ can be neglected since it can be bounded somehow, and I'm trying to play with the terms  $e^{\pm R}$ in order to get something, but it always gets messy.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the *complex* sine can be bounded somehow?And what is $\;\omega\;$ ?

Comment: You are not evaluating the sine in the whole complex plane, just in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0\leq Im(z)\leq\pi\}$. That's why I think that it can be bounded.

Comment: What is $\;\omega\;$ ?

Comment: That is just a real number. Originally this is a problem in dynamical systems, where you have the perturbed system  \begin{equation}\label{sistema}
     \left\{\begin{array}{l}
        \dot x = y,\\
        \dot y =-\sin(x)+\epsilon\cos(\omega t).
        \end{array}\right.
    \end{equation} and you try to compute its Melnikov function, which is given by $$M(\theta_0)=\int_\mathbb{R}-\sqrt{2}\mbox{sech}(t)\tanh(t)\cos(\omega (t+\theta_0))dt.$$

Comment: I think you should add this to the question: $\;\omega\in\Bbb R\;$

Comment: Yes I already added it.